# Div suddenly became unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project to explain jQuery to my students. I had a div that would slide on click and then added a second to hide. Then nothing worked so I removed all new code but the slide div no longer works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // slide function
        $("#frog").click(function() {
            $("#frog").animate({left: "200px"}, 500);
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #frog{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>I hate JS!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <h2>Programming Languages</h2>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>Javascript</li>
        <li>C++</li>
        <li>C#</li>
        <li>ruby</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <h2>Top 3 Best Animations</h2>
        <h4><li>Slide</li></h4>

    <div id="frog"></div>
    </ol>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. This can break any javascript as elements get rendered wrong. It should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <h2>Programming Languages</h2>
    <li>Python</li>
    <li>Javascript</li>
    <li>C++</li>
    <li>C#</li>
    <li>ruby</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li><h2>Top 3 Best Animations</h2></li>
    <li>
      <h4>Slide</h4>
      <div id="frog"></div>
    </li>
</ol>
<script>//javascript here</script>
```

Also, it is strongly recommended to include your JS **before your closing body tag**. Because when the javascript initiates, the element it has to bind to, has to exist first! If the javascript renders before the element does, it will never be able to find it, therefore not work, so include javascripts at the *end of your document, not the start*.

You also need to wrap your javascript within a

```
$(function(){
 //Javascript here
});
```

So that it will trigger on all browsers when the page has finished loading. (Not all browsers automatically trigger javascripts)

See this JS fiddle for a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5cxnLe4v/1/

-- also slightly important: make sure you close all your elements, like the `</body>` and `</html>`!

Comment: *"You also need to wrap your javascript within a"* well... not if he moves it like you suggested...